# I got a jquery comment plugin for my blog,but i dont know where does the comments gets stored?

Tags: jquery, html, css, plugins

Header

```
<title>EasyComment Sample</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery.easy-comment.min"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// Your other javascript code if any

$("my-comment").EasyComment({
  path:"example.com/easy-comment", //Change it to the folder where you put the easycomment files
  moderate:false,
  maxReply:5
});
// Your other javascript code if any
});
</script>
```

Body

```
<h3>EasyComment Sample</h3>
<div id="my-comment" style="width:800px;height:800px;"></div>
```

Really couldn't find, even comments doesn't show up. Should I do some server side scripting for this to work? If so please guide me tysm

Comment: Could we see the comment plugin?

Comment: yeah i saw it,i typed some in it,but it wasn't storing information i typed

Comment: Please include any console error output as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need a "#" infront of "my-comment" to select the Id

```
$("#my-comment").EasyComment({
  path:"rechargedroid.com/easy-comment", //Change it to the folder where you put the easycomment files
  moderate:false,
  maxReply:5
})
```

;

Comment: Sure ill give it a try,can you pls say where the typed data will be saved,else i must program again in server side script or like that?

Comment: Sorry, not really sure what you mean here, but there should be documentation from the provider of the plugin that will explain how to configure your server.  But as long as the code provided for your plugin is correct, my answer will fix your jQuery problem

Comment: sure thanks,will add # ,yes i got set i things to be made from http://www.jswidget.com/lab/easy-comment.html

Comment: you are also going to want to place the jquery.easy-comment.min file on your server and reference it  using your own domain:
<script type="text/javascript" src="htt p://YOURDOMAIN.com/jquery.easy-comment.min"></script>